# Latitude and longitude of fuel pumps in the uk

Tags: geospatial, gas, fuel

I am after a dataset of latitude and longitude of all fuel pumps in the United Kingdom. Is there any free (or paid) resource for that?

Answer (score 1):

OpenStreetMap has a lot of data relative to [gas stations](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity%3Dfuel), including (obviously) coordinates. You can use [overpass turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu) to retrieve this data. In the overpass turbo interface, zoom on your zone of interest, and run the following query:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
nwr["amenity"="fuel"]({{bbox}});
// print results
out geom;
```

Execute the query, then you'll be able to export the data in various open source formats (geoJSON, KML, etc.) for treatment in geographic information system software.

When you run your query, make sure to zoom on a sufficiently small zone, otherwise your request may time out. Also, it may be a good idea to read the [OSM documentation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity%3Dfuel) to make sure this is *really* the data you're after.

If you need to convert the data to another format (csv, excel, or whatever), then this is a question you may want to ask on https://gis.stackexchange.com/ or possibly https://stackoverflow.com/, but then you should make extremely clear what is the specific result you're looking for (what variables you need, etc.). If you're able to write some programming scripts, [geoJSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON) is a quite straightforward format to work with, so it should be pretty easy to convert the data to a format you're looking for. Otherwise, there might be online tools to do that for you, but I didn't look for it.